# How do you get browsers to recognize a password change?

Tags: html, passwords

As I'm sure you are aware, a feature on most browsers is that they save passwords.  Now, I have a site where a user can change their password on one of the pages.  Is there a way to get the browser to recognize the change?

In other words, the I want the browsers to bring up their "save new password" dialog when a user enters their new password in a certain field.  Is there a way to do this?

Obviously, a pure html solution is preferred, but I'd be happy to hear of ways to do this in Javascript.

FYI, the site I am working does not require very strong security.

Comment: How can you change a file from the browser stored via local files from HTML? You can't.

Comment: I am wondering there is a to indicate to the browser that you would like it to do that.

Comment: One more observation.  The behavior I want occurs automatically on Firefox, but not IE or Chrome.  I am starting to think that Chrome and IE cannot be made to operate in the manner I want.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as `<INPUT TYPE="password" AUTOCOMPLETE="on" ...`